# nginx www redirect to non-www with subdomain

Tags: redirect, nginx

How can i redirect from www to non www for this rule ~^(?\w+).example.com ?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.example\.com$;
}
```

I try separate main domain redirect and all subdomains redirect but have recursive redirection for main domain.

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
     server_name "~^www\.(.*)$" ;
     return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri ;
}
```

Then i try only

```
server {
     server_name "~^www\.(.*)$" ;
     return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri ;
}
```

and that work for subdomains. But in main domain i have redirect for $request_uri without domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to remember is that if `nginx` cannot find a matching `server_name` it will use the default server. And unless you define a `default_server`, it will use the first `server` block listening on the appropriate port. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

Clearly `example.com` does not match the regular expression `~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.example\.com$`, however, your current `server` block works because it is the implicit default server.

Regular expression `server` blocks are evaluated in order, so place the `www.` rule first so that `www.example.com` is not treated as a subdomain.

Make the main `server` block default explicitly so that it continues to handle `example.com`.

```
server {
    server_name "~^www\.(.*)$" ;
    return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri ;
}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.example\.com$;
    ...
}
```